# Best practice for calling one fragment's method, from another fragment, which are both contained inside a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android

I currently have 3 `Fragments` being hosted inside a `ViewPager`, which extends the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

I am currently instantiating all 3 fragments inside their own `newIntance` method:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String key) {

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY, value);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

Fragment1 displays information from my database.
Fragment3 allows you to amend the database.

When Fragment 3 updates the database, I want to call the `updateUI` method in Fragment1, so that when you scroll back to it via the `ViewPager`, you can see the new data.

I have so far chosen to do this by applying the following code in Fragment3:

```
Fragment1 fragment = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:2131362005:0");
if (fragment != null) {
    fragment.updateUI();
}
```

I chose this method, as there is no way to set a tag (or id), using the `newInstance` method (that I could find).

I found that this tag (android:switcher:2131362005:0) was the correct tag being used at the time, through calling `Log.d` and using the `getTag` method. The only problem is that it seems as though the tag is not fixed every time you load the application, so it is redundant.

I am your classic 'Learning via the textbook' android developer and would appreciate any guidance. There's got to be a way of setting an ID or Tag to reference!?

Comment: if you pull your data from database inside fragment 1, you dont need to refresh ui from the fragment 3. When you swipe back to fragment 1, it will already pull new data from database.

Comment: When I swipe back to fragment 1, the old data is being displayed. I am calling the updateUI in the onResume() method inside Fragment1 as well. The Fragment is being kept in memory via the Activities: pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2).

Comment: I've fashioned a plaster solution by just reducing the OffscreenPagerLimit to just 1, that way Fragment1 gets destroyed once you up Fragment3. The reloading of the fragment isn't causing a performance issue either. However, if anyone has the true solution, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an interface and hold your data inside activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements DataChangeListener{

    private List<YourDataClass> yourDataList; //your data will be displayed in fragment 1

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        yourDataList = pull from db..

        //when u create instance of fragment3, u should set DataChangeListener
        Fragment fragment3 = Fragment3.newInstance();
        fragment3.setDataChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void getDataList(){
      return yourDataList;
    }

    @Override
    void onDataChange(){
      yourDataList = pull from db to see new values..
    }

    public interface DataChangeListener{
      void onDataChange();
    }

    .
    .
    .
}


//fragment to display data
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

  private List<YourDataClass> yourDataList;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    yourDataList = ((YourActivity) getActivity()).getDataList();
  }

  .
  .
  .
}


//fragment to update data
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment{

    private DataChangeListener listener;

    public void setDataChangeListener(DataChangeListener dataChangeListener){
        this.listener = dataChangeListener;
    }

    private void methodToUpdateDb(){
      //update db..
      .
      .
      listener.onDataChange();  //after updating db, then call listener and data 
    will be changed
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```